# How many Wintersday mini pets will I be able to make?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have been doing the Wintersday Tixx instance every day since it was added, and so far I have built up a nice collection of frames, glue, stuffing, and mystical cogs;

[image]

So far I've made the painted doll pet, will I be able to make the other pets this year or am I going to end up with more frames than other materials?

Is it possible to get the account bound mystical cogs from other sources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to game designer Anthony Ordon:

> [You’ll have enough to make any two you’d like if you play all five days.](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/wintersday/Tixx-Minipets/first#post1007757)

But:

> [Any rewards tied to a specific day will be attainable when those days are available for replay at the end.](http://blacklionsprofit.com/wintersday/anthony-ordon-discusses-wintersday/)

While Tixx is in Lion's Arch, you will be able to select which frame you want to build at the start of the event.  If you have not built this frame before, you will receive the frame, 100 cogs, and 250 glue/stuffing.  If you have built the frame before  you will have your choice of Wintersday gifts.

<s>By talking to Tixx in Lion's Arch, you will also gain access to the cheat beside him which will contain an additional 200 cogs.  Things brings the total number of attainable cogs to 700.</s>

[The Wintersday finale gift was changed from being a chest in Lion's Arch to being a mailed gift.](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Game_updates/2012-12-21)  In this gift, you will receive 250 cogs (among other things).  You will receive this even if you opened the chest pre-patch.

### This brings the total number of possible cogs to 950 meaning you can make 3 minis!

Comment: But the 'rewards' on a specific day includes the mystical cogs, glue and stuffing, does this mean you'll get more of these during the replay at the end, or are the replays at the end only going to give you frames?

Comment: @pixel See quote #1

Comment: Also worth noting - you an use the frames to craft Wintersday tonics and endless tonics as well.

Comment: Also also worth noting - you can get extra frames for 250 sweaters.

Comment: Three minis! It's a Wintersday miracle!

Comment: Woo! I now have three pets \o/