# What can I do with my remaining Mystical Cogs after crafting minis?

Tags: guild-wars-2

There are five different versions of Tixx's Infinarium, each one rewarding you with 100 [Mystical Cogs](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystical_Cog) when completed. Finishing all five grants you another 200, for a total of 700 cogs.

Each holiday mini pet requires 250 cogs to craft. [This means that you can only craft two](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96558/how-many-wintersday-mini-pets-will-i-be-able-to-make).

What are the remaining 200 cogs good for?

Comment: Considering that I also have 250 of one of the other materials, and three frames left after constructing two of the mini pets, it's possible that we're expected to keep the materials until next year, which will allow us to construct the remaining three pets next year (assuming they don't add more). It is of course possible that there are some yet-unknown recipes that uses them at the Mystic Forge...

Comment: @pixel: The leftover toy frames and magic glue/stuffing can be [used to make tonics](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Endless_Toy_Ventari_Tonic), but they don't require cogs. (You can acquire extra frames in exchange for sweaters/hats/socks, and glue/stuffing on the TP)

Comment: Yes but the question is about cogs! Not glue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one day, there was a bug where mystic cogs suffered from Dungeon Diminishing Returns. I.e., if you completed another dungeon, then ran Tixx's dungeon, you would get less than 200 mystic cogs.

As far as I'm aware, this was Anet's 'fix' for those adversely affected, so that everyone has enough mystic cogs to make exactly 2 minis, as 200 extra cogs is not enough for someone *not* affected by the bug to get another one.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no other use for the mystic cogs --- at least, this year!

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to just accept loosing two bank slots.